# Use tikzdevice in quarto pdf, but standard output in html

Tags: knitr, quarto, tikzdevice

When writing for publication, I greatly prefer the `tikzDevice` functionality of `knitr`, as it renders my plots in the same font as the document (among other things). I see that Quarto does this nicely in the PDF rendering. Here's a MWE:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  pdf: default
  html: default
editor: visual
---

See the example in @fig-example

```{r, dev = 'tikz'}
#| label: fig-example
#| fig-cap: Example figure.
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point()
```
````

And the PDF output:
[image: PDF output]

But when rendering to html, it tries to embed the PDF of the figure in a window:

[image: HTML output]

In bookdown, I could do something like `dev = if(knitr::is_latex_output()){'tikz'}}` but that doesn't seem to work in Quarto. I can also set the device with the global
chunk option

```
knitr: 
  opts_chunk: 
    dev: 'tikz'
```

But this seems to apply to both PDF and html as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this chunk to the front of the document seems to work, but it's a little bit clunky. I'm curious if there are any options that involve the YAML header options.

````
```{r}
if(knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'tikz')
}
```
````